# hvplot call inside function does not display in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews, hvplot

I am new to hvplot and trying to include a call to `.hvplot()` inside a function definition, but it's not working. The following code works and displays a figure as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 5, 3, 4, 2])
df.hvplot()
```

but if I try something like:

```
def plot(df):
    df.hvplot()
plot(df)
```

I get no output. This is in a Jupyter Notebook. What am I missing?

Comment: The way to think about this is that an hvplot works the same as a string or integer: if you want to display the string or integer in a notebook, you either need to call `display()` on it, or you need to make sure it's returned as the value of the notebook cell (i.e., is the value of the last line of the cell). Same for a .hvplot(); it displays if displayed explicitly or returned as the value of the cell. Here the value of the cell is None, because your function returns None, so nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the result of your function:

```py
def plot(df):
    return df.hvplot()

plot(df)
```

Or:

```py
def plot(df):
    my_plot = df.hvplot()
    return my_plot

plot(df)
```

Comment: Alternatively you can call `display(df.hvplot())`